# Scikit-learn Gaussian HMM error: ValueError: startprob must sum to 1.0

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am currently working with Scikit Learn and have been running into the following issue while trying to train a Gaussian HMM.

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\hmm.py", line 476, in _set_startprob
    raise ValueError('startprob must sum to 1.0')
ValueError: startprob must sum to 1.0
```

When running the function as such:

```
model = GaussianHMM(n_components=5, covariance_type="diag", n_iter=1000,
                            means_prior=means_prior, means_weight=0.5)
```

This works about 1/10 times without error, but 9/10 times, it throws the error. Decreasing the number of components increases the likelyhood of working without error.

I have also tried to force the startprob to `startprob=[0.20, 0.20, 0.20, 0.20, 0.20]` with no increased luck.

I have also used `print model.startprob_` to ensure that the startprob was `[0.20, 0.20, 0.20, 0.20, 0.20]`.

Any ideas what the issue is?

Comment: Can you try installing the dev version of `scikit-learn` and see if that fixes things? There's recently been a large bug fix for Gaussian HMMs that's not in stable yet.

`easy_install pip; pip install -e 'git+git@github.com:scikit-learn/scikit-learn.git#egg=scikit-learn-0.15-git'` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. I think it depends on the number of the input sequences. If I have too little sequences to build a model I get this error that's because this model is not convincing enough. And the more components you take the more appropriate data you need. But it is only my assumption.